# Self-adjoint lift of idempotent in quotient

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $I\subseteq A$ a closed ideal. Let $a\in A$ be such that $a^2-a\in I$.

**Question:** Can one construct an element $b\in A$ in terms of $a$ such that $b$ is a self-adjoint lift of $[a]$?

*Remark:* By a lift I mean $[b]=[a]\in A/I$.

Comment: Do you mean $a^2-a\in I$?

Comment: In any case, you certainly cannot construct such an element $b$ without additionally assuming that $[a]$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\in A$ is such that $[a]$ is self-adjoint, then $b=\frac{a+a^*}{2}$ is self-adjoint and satisfies $[b]=\frac{[a]+[a]^*}{2}=[a]$.  Conversely, if such a $b$ exists, then clearly $[a]=[b]$ must be self-adjoint.  So assuming that $[a]$ is idempotent is not relevant; instead, such a $b$ exists iff $[a]$ is self-adjoint.